# I have run into a problem while hosting an angular application on Azure

Tags: angular, azure-web-app-service

I have run into a problem while hosting an angular application on Azure.

I am trying to host my angular application on Azure using VS Code. When i run the Azure App Server i get the following error.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/ResourceManagement/runtime-es2015.858f8dd898b75fe86926.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/ResourceManagement/polyfills-es2015.a3f585d393ecee6ff04d.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
scripts.00866a06f9144eb57493.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/ResourceManagement/main-es2015.f0fcb0bd3957ea1298d6.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
styles.f3e57793e0e36a1a66da.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

When i checked in my **dist folder** and can see those files in Azure Repository.
Can any one guide me on this issue. I am new to Azure.

Comment: It looks like you put the release file in the wrong place.

Comment: dist/ResourceManagement is the folder where release files are when ng build --prod is run. So that is the path given by me.

Comment: This is why you are wrong.

Comment: You should deploy the contents of the ResourceManagement folder to the wwwroot folder.

Comment: If you use linux, you should add startup command with `npx serve -s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jason Pan said, you should put the files in `dist` to `wwwroot`. `https://angulardeploydist.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`
[image]

For Linux app, add startup command with `npx serve -s`:
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Jason Pan & Doris Lv. It worked for me. I am using windows and as suggested I moved the contents of ResourceMangement folder to dist folder. One more change i had to do is that i had to remove web.config file from dist folder. It was causing some conflict with my parent web.config file. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear you solve this. Would you mind accept my reply as the answer for others to refer? @viraj